# Statistics on an amplitude-time graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, statistics, parameter-passing

MATLAB - I have data of amplitude and time, and I am trying to ascertain the times at which the peaks in amplitude are.  My most recent attempt, seen here, involves the `findpeaks` function.  However, I would like to get the `MinPeakHeight` parameter, which comes directly from the graph of the data and is seen here as 0.2, to be more accurate and general.  Is there some statistical or other way to do this?

```
y = y(:,1);
dt = 1 / Fs;
t =  0 : dt : (length(y) * dt) - dt;

[pks,index] = findpeaks(y,'MinPeakHeight',0.2);
pksTimes = t(index);
```

I hope that this is clear, but, if not, I am more than happy to clarify any points.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a graph of the data?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, here is a screenshot of the graph: http://prntscr.com/k5uub2

Comment: I think you are probably looking for a [Cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) to separate the low-amplitude peaks from higher ones. Alternatively, if you are dealing with waveforms similar to the one in the picture, you could probably take the [prominence output from findpeaks](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#bufbbs1-p), and calculate an average prominence, multiply that by a factor, then take the product as a threshold to filter out any peaks with lower prominence.